# I can't see input value in my form in angular5

Tags: angular, typescript

My code in HTML

```
<input type="text" name="fechainscripcion" #fechainscripcion="ngModel" [(ngModel)]="alumno.fechainscripcion" value="{{today | date:'dd/MM/yyyy'}}" class="form-control" />
```

My component

```
this.today = Date.now();
this.title = 'Añadir';
this.alumno = new Alumno('','','','','','',null,'','','Alta');
```

In the array of alumno the value of fechainscripcion is null.

I want to see value "{{today | date:'dd/MM/yyyy'}}" in the input.

Comment: which value do you see instead? - i guess that the value of your `alumno.fechainscripcion` model overwrites the value

Comment: `export class Alumno{
 constructor(
  public _id: string,
  public name: string, 
  public description: string,
  public year: string, 
  public image: string, 
  public user: string,
  public fechainscripcion: string,
  public cuota: string,
  public genero: string, 
  public estado: string,
 ){}
}`

Answer (score 0):

Remove the `[(ngModel)]` directive, for starters, and then use `[value]="..."`

If you use `value` without the '[]' Angular sets it to literally what you put into the quotes. Anyway, in this case it does not matter, because `ngModel` sets the value too, to `null`.

If what you want is for the input to indicate the current date by default, set that date in the `Alumno` constructor instead of `null`.

Comment: `[value]=" ... "` or `value="{{ ... }}"`, but not a mix of both

Comment: Yes, well spotted :-)

Comment: It would be nice to explain why removing [(ngModel)] helps?

Comment: I already do: 'in this case it does not matter, because `ngModel` sets the value too, to `null`'

Comment: If I remove the NGMODEL I will not be able to capture the value of the input in the array  and  this works value="{{today | date:'dd/MM/yyyy'}}" but with [value]="today | date:'dd/MM/yyyy'" didn't work   thx for the help

Comment: As I said, if you need to update a value and have that same value in the input, always initialize the `alumno` property and set its `fechainscripcion` to the current date instead of `null`. In any case, you can't have both `value` and `ngModel` in the same control, as they conflict with each other

Comment: But how i can put in the alumno.fechainscription the property of pipe | date:'dd/MM/yyyy'}} if i can resolve that its the end of the question.  thx very much for all your help

Answer (score 0):

`{{}}` should be used for interpolation. However it does not matter here as you are binding the input element using ngModel. Either remove the section: `[(ngModel)]="alumno.fechainscripcion"`

or else put the value of date in alumno.